# Show that for $n>3$, there is always a $2$-regular graph on $n$ vertices. For what values of $n>4$ will there be a 3-regular graph on n vertices?

Tags: graph-theory

Show that for $n>3$, there is always a $2$-regular graph on $n$ vertices. For what values of $n>4$ will there be a 3-regular graph on n vertices?

I think this question is slightly out of my control. Can you please help me out with this question...

For part two what I think is yes by handshaking I will exclude all the odd vertices as $3(2n+1)$ is not even number. So what should be the answer? All even number of vertices? Does that make sense?
And for part 1 it is obviously true but how can I proceed to the answer?
Thanks.

Comment: For part 1, any cycle of length $n$ does the work

Comment: I know, like it is pretty obvious but how can I prove this!

Comment: I don't think there is much more to prove for part 1. If your $n$ vertices are $v_1, \dots, v_n$ you connect $v_i$ and $v_{i+1}$ for all $1\leq i \leq n-1$, as well as $v_1$ and $v_n$, and you just see that every vertex has degree $2$

Comment: Okay makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For part 1, consider the cycle of length $n$, so the statement is true. For part 2, the number of edges is $3n/2$
so the number of vertices must be even. It must be also at least 6 by assumption. For $n=4$ the square with two diagonals is the answer.  For every even $n=2m\ge 6$ consider the dihedral group $D_m$. It is generated by 3 involutions. The Cayley graph corresponding to this generating set is 3-regular with $n$ verticed.

Comment: So basically the solution of part b will be same as I indicated in question?

Comment: Like I haven't studied that dihedral group or probably in my country it is named something else. Summing up, is whatever I said about part two is correct or not?

Comment: Thanks! For your time and help

Comment: Got it, thanks again

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is what JCAA is referring to but for part 2, if you have an even number $2n$ ($n \geq 3$) of vertices $v_1, \dots, v_n$ and $u_1, \dots, u_n$, you can just consider the two cycles $v_1, \dots, v_n$ and $u_1, \dots, u_n$ and add the edges $\{v_i,u_i\}$ for all $1 \leq i \leq n$. The resulting graph will be 3-regular.

As you mentioned, it obviously fails for odd number of vertices because the sum of degrees in a graph is always even since it is twice the number of edges.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't get your point. Like how can we consider two cycles in here? Isn't it mean that some of the vertices will have degree 2 while others will have degree 3?

Comment: You just split your $2n$ vertices into two sets of $n$ vertices $V = \{v_1, \dots , v_n\}$ and $U = \{u_1, \dots, u_n\}$, which you both turn separately into cycles of length $n$. Then you connect $v_i$ and $u_i$ for all $1 \leq i \leq n$. A vertex of the set $V$ will have two neighbors in $V$, and one neighbor in $U$. Similarly, a vertex of the set $U$ will have two neighbors in $U$, and one neighbor in $V$. The graph will thus be 3-regular. It really helps drawing the graph if you cannot clearly see it ;)

Comment: Never mind, I got your point. It makes sense too.

Comment: I really appreciate your help and work, thanks

Comment: It is also the Cayley graph of dihedral group but with respect to the two generators $a, b$: $a^m=b^2=1, bab= a^{-1} $.